# How to extract data from HTML using beuatiful soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a web page and store the results in a csv/excel file. I am using beautiful soup for this.

I am trying to extract the data from a soup , using the find_all function, but I am not sure how to capture the data in the field name or title

The HTML file has the following format

```
<h3 class="font20">
 <span itemprop="position">36.</span> 
 <a class="font20 c_name_head weight700 detail_page" 
 href="/companies/view/1033/nimblechapps-pvt-ltd" target="_blank" 
 title="Nimblechapps Pvt. Ltd."> 
     <span itemprop="name">Nimblechapps Pvt. Ltd. </span>
</a> </h3>
```

This is my code so far. Not sure how to proceed from here

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests 
page = 'https://www.goodfirms.co/directory/platform/app-development/iphone? 
page=2'
res = requests.get(page)
cont = BS(res.content, "html.parser")
names = cont.find_all(class_ = 'font20 c_name_head weight700 detail_page')
names = cont.find_all('a' , attrs = {'class':'font20 c_name_head weight700 
detail_page'})
```

I have tried using the following -

```
Input: cont.h3.a.span
Output: <span itemprop="name">Nimblechapps Pvt. Ltd.</span>
```

I want to extract the name of the company - "Nimblechapps Pvt. Ltd."

Comment: Post the code you have tried, and what the specific problem with it is.

Comment: @ScottHunter done! Please check the edited version of the question

Comment: You want `cont.h3.a.span.text` ?

Comment: To get tag attributes use `tag[attr]`, to get tag text use `tag.text`. Note that `.find_all()` returns a list of elements. If you want only the first use `.find()` or select by index.

Comment: @t.m.adam I want to return the list of company names on the webpage. How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: @drec4s yes I want cont.h3.a.span.text. But I need it for all the listing provided on the webpage! I am unable to return the list

Comment: Easy, select the text of each element, eg: `for tag in cont.find_all("span", itemprop="name"): print(tag.text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension for that:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests

page = 'https://www.goodfirms.co/directory/platform/app-development/iphone?page=2'
res = requests.get(page)
cont = BS(res.content, "html.parser")
names = cont.find_all('a' , attrs = {'class':'font20 c_name_head weight700 detail_page'})
print([n.text for n in names])
```

You will get:

```
['Nimblechapps Pvt. Ltd.', (..) , 'InnoApps Technologies Pvt. Ltd', 'Umbrella IT', 'iQlance Solutions', 'getyoteam', 'JetRuby Agency LTD.', 'ONLINICO', 'Dedicated Developers', 'Appingine', 'webnexs']
```

Answer (score 1):

Same thing but using descendant combinator `" "` to combine the type selector `a` with attribute = value selector `[itemprop="name"]`

```
names = [item.text for item in cont.select('a [itemprop="name"]')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try not to use compound classes within the script as they are prone to break. The following script should fetch you the required content as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.goodfirms.co/directory/platform/app-development/iphone?page=2"

res = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for items in soup.find_all(class_="commoncompanydetail"):
    names = items.find(class_='detail_page').text
    print(names)
```